# OnClickListner interface is not working for linearlayout in the fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

I am creating a fragment in which I'm using a clickable linearLayout as a button
I have created all the necessary methods and implemented the OnClickListener interface to the class but when i click the layout nothing happens
Here is my LinearLayout and TextView from xml and java code.

```
          <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"

            android:background="@drawable/button_layout"
            android:layout_margin="1dip">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="e"
                    android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_dark"
                    android:gravity="top"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:text="π"
                    android:gravity="bottom"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

The mainview TextView is

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/mainview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/button_material_light"
            android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Class code is

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

TextView mainView;
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mainView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainview);


}

public static HomeFragment newInstance(int i){
    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("index", i);
    homeFragment.setArguments(args);
    return homeFragment;
}

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt("index"));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    mainView.setText("ghalib");
 }
}
```

I also tried debugging the program and find out that the method is not called on clicking the Layout.

Comment: Are you sure that, you have added the mainView.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: Thanks....rahul i found the solution i forgot the to set the listner of my LinearLayout and by the way mainView is my TextView which is not clickable in my layout

Comment: Hey @rahul is it possible to use "this" Object for onclicklistner in xml

Comment: Since your Activity implements the interface, you can pass the class context (this) and it will delegate to the overriding method (onClick) written in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to rahul to remind me to pass the "this" Object in the setOnClickListener of the Clickable LinearLayout Which I'm using as the Button

So first I assign the id to the layout by android:id="@+id/pie"
then setting the listner in the code then the new code is

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

TextView mainView;
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mainView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainview);

    //This is the New Part
    ((LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pie))
    .setOnClickListener(this);

}

public static HomeFragment newInstance(int i){
    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("index", i);
    homeFragment.setArguments(args);
    return homeFragment;
}

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    ((MainActivity)activity).
    onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt("index"));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    mainView.setText("ghalib");
 }
}
```